Request remains pending and it never times out
Is there a browser-imposed default setting where a request is closed if the server doesn't respond after a certain amount of time?
I have this simple NodeJS example:
const app = require("express")();
const cors = require("cors");

app.use(cors());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {

});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("App is up");
});


As you can notice inside app.get() the response is never sent back by the server.
On the front-end I send a request like this:
console.time('Req')
fetch('http://localhost:3000').catch((e) => {
  console.timeEnd('Req')
})

I would expect that the browser will close the request after a given time, but this never happens and the request remains in the PENDING state.
I've tried this in Chrome, Edge and Firefox.
Is this the default behavior?

How long have you tried waiting? I gave up after 10 minutes! I have no evidence to support it, but it does seem that fetch will wait for a long time for a response. You could of course add {signal:AbortSignal.timeout(1000)} to all your fetch calls like this to have them only wait 1 second in this case

I waited 9 hours. Same here, I haven't found anything official to support it, but it seems the request stays open until it's closed by the server. Therefore, there is no default mechanism by the browser to stop a request after a certain time if the server does not respond. That's what I was expecting, but I didn't find anything official.

as I said, {signal:AbortSignal.timeout(1000)} in the fetch options will do it - it's "official" in as much as it's how to timeout a fetch :p
